pandas to_excel export numerically inacurrate
I have a Pandas DataFrame that I want to export to Excel.
When doing so using pd.to_excel(...) my floats are getting slightly faulty.
Something like:
df = [0.019,2.117,9.999]

excel = [0.018999901104,2.11700000111,9.999997711454]

All I want is that the Excel valuer are the same as the original values in the df.
Maybe there is a way to do this?
Thank you

Have you tried rounding (.round()) your values before exporting to Excel?

yes I did and it didn't help

None of these three decimal numbers can be represented as binary floats just like ⅔ can't be represented as a decimal number. That doesn't mean there's no way to store them correctly in Excel though.

You can set the display precision in Excel. Whether that is of any help depends on your use case. What do you need the Excel file for?

Weird. I've tried chaining df.round(3).to_excel('test.xlsx') and it returned the exact decimal places in Excel, as in df

my company need this Excel for some reason I do not know :( the Excel is showing the precision needed but the real value by selecting one cell is my example

I don't have the same problem with the same sample, but if it happens to you, try saving as str dtype and exporting to excel and fixing the data type in excel.

If Wikipedia is to be trusted, it is in fact impossible to store these exact numbers as numbers in Excel because Excel only stores numbers in binary format:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel However, there should be a way to ensure that the numbers are accurate to 15 decimal places.

In my case I couldn't replicate the same error as yours. Recall to add a minimal reproducible example when possible.
Nonetheless, the float_format should handle your case
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([0.019, 2.117, 9.999], columns=['values'])

float_format = '%.3f'  
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', float_format=float_format, index=False)

Result in Excel:

